# confusion coming from the slice method in JavaScript involving a if statement

Tags: javascript, methods

I was reading a JavaScript book and this example was shown...

```js
var text = "Relics of World War II were found";
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text.slice(i, i + 12) === "World War II") {
    text = text.slice(0, i) + "the Second World War" + text.slice(i + 12);
  }
}
console.log(text);
```

I understood that the code's purpose is to find the banned segment(World War II) and replace it with "the Second World War". The thing that knocked me off guard was the use of (i) with (12) in the slice method. I wanted to know why 12 was put in there along side (i), I know "World War II" is 12 characters but *what* does it do?

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: I converted your code into a runnable snippet. I suggest you uncomment the `console.log` inside the loop and try running it to see what you get, hopefully that will help you understand how it works.

Comment: @Nick Thank you, I wasn't sure if I was should have wrote what the value of (text) was, so I appreciate you fixing that. I was also (funny enough) confused when my question's code changed but soon realized that this was something that can be done in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DeC Someone changed it for me and gave it a value, if you'd like to see.

Comment: @SamaAbbas 12 is because of the length of the `"World War II"`, which is 12. You want to replace this with `"the Second World War"`.

Comment: @DeC Okay, I think I get it now, Thank you :)

Comment: @SamaAbbas Miu answer is not right. You can check https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/dyOEQOx?editors=0011 ... slice second parameter is not count i.e how many. Instead, it is up to endIndex.

Comment: `'abcdef'.slice(2, 3)` is not equal to `"cde"`. It is equal to `c`

Comment: @SamaAbbas no worries. You'll get used to questions (and answers) being edited, it doesn't happen often but when there's a chance to improve the post with a simple change you'll usually find someone will make it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The length of `"World War II"` is 12 including spaces.
- A given text is not only `"World War II"` but also perhaps `"Something something World War II something."`.
- `text.slice(i, i + 12)` indicates just `"World War II"` in the given text.
- `string.slice(<startIndex>, <lastIndex>)` extracts a part of a string.

  - `'abcdefg'.slice(0, 3)` = `'abc'`
  - `'abcdefg'.slice(2, 3)` = `'c'`
  - `'abcdefg'.slice(3)` = `'defg'`
  - `'abcdefg'.slice(0, 3) + 'XYZ' + 'abcdefg'.slice(3)` = `'abcXYZdefg'`

```js
function replaceWW2(text) {
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text.slice(i, i + 12) === "World War II") {
      text = text.slice(0, i) + "the Second World War" + text.slice(i + 12);
    }
  }
  
  return text;
}

console.log(replaceWW2('World War II'));

// World War II = text.slice(20, 20+12)
console.log(replaceWW2('I was a baby during World War II.'));
```

Comment: `string.slice(<start index>, <how many>)` this is wrong. Slice second parameter is not `count` i.e how many. It is endIndex.

Comment: `'abcdef'.slice(2, 3)` is not equal to `"cde"`. It is equal to `"c"`

Comment: check https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/dyOEQOx?editors=0011

Comment: understanding right and understanding easy, both are different. We cannot understand an easy thing if it is not right.

Comment: That's better 

Comment: Thank you for your edit :) I have fixed my answer a little too. Since you wrote `<lastIndex>`, I changed `<start index>` to `<startIndex>` :) Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) extracts a part of a string and returns it as a new string without modifying the original string.

**Parameters**

1. *BeginIndex*: It is the starting index from where the extraction begins. It is a zero-based index.
2. *endIndex*: It is the end index up to the string extract. It is also a zero-based index. If the endIndex is `omitted` or `greater` than the length of the string, then string extraction is up to the end of the string.

What your code snippet does is it first extract string as a new string(where begin index is `i` and endIndex is `i+12`) i.e `text.slice(i, i + 12)`, then it compares this extracted string with `"World War II"`.

> `text = text.slice(0, i) + "the Second World War" + text.slice(i + 12);`

So the above snippet replaces `"World War II"` with `"the Second World War"`. It contains 2 parts as follows:

- `text.slice(0, i)`: It slice the `text` from starting index up to the current iteration(up to `i`).
- `text.slice(i + 12)`: It slices the `text` from the current iteration(from `i+12`) upto the end of the `text`(upto `text.length`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The slice method is similar to substr method in SQL and other programming languages.
The first parameter is the start of the string, the second parameter is the length of the string plus the length of the word.

For example, if the sentence said: "Germany started World War II"
then i would be 15, and i+12 would be 27.

If the second parameter is omitted, then it will assume to the length of the array.